# UITextView, scroll while editing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextview

I've got a big `UITextView`, nearly full screen. If I tap it, the keyboard pops up and I can edit the text. However, the longer I type, eventually the text runs down the view, behind the keyboard. I can no longer see what I'm typing.

How do you deal with this? Do you have to track the cursor position and scroll the view manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have to size your UITextView as keyboard shows/hides. So the keyboard won't be over your textview. Here is the sample codes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    CGRect endRect = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect newRect = YOUT_TEXT_VIEW.frame;
    //Down size your text view
    newRect.size.height -= endRect.size.height;
    YOUT_TEXT_VIEW.frame = newRect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ... // Resize your textview when keyboard is going to hide
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use following code for scroll down textview according to text range(or say according to typing)

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 1);
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: Thanx for response..but i got link what i want to do..below link  which is work fine.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html

Comment: @user1328096 For posterity can you write the solution to your question as a proper answer? (And don't forget to accept some answers!)

Comment: @adamjansch : Totally agree. Why people asking question if they have already solution.? I think. for only "" Increase the stack of Stack overflow""

Comment: NO dear i Searching for this problem for last 2 hours ..but i am unable to find the best solution.but when i post question .after 5 Minut i got link .thats why i post link to help some one others.sorry Dear if u mind it...

Answer (score 2):

TPKeyboardAvoiding is an excellent tool that handles all the scrolling to avoid a keyboard for you. /Very/ handy and highly recommended. See: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: Wow, what a gem TPKeyboardAvoiding is!